# Change text color in adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

I need to change text color in of list view with switch of a button click. List view with custom adapter and custom layout. Text view in `newsitemlist_layout.xml` inflated with adapter normal it works fine but in fragment gives an error:

> Adaptor.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference

The problem is that adapter is initialized in fragment and switch or button in main activity if I implement change text color in fragment it works but not in main activity. Is there any way to do this?

MainActivity.java:

```
NewsAdaptor adaptor;
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick ( View view ) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
});

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);


aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged ( CompoundButton buttonView, boolean   isChecked ) {

           adaptor.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
           } else {


            adaptor.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
   }
});
```

Fragment.java

```
NewsAdaptor adapter;
adapter = new NewsAdaptor(Main2Activity.this, newsItemsList);
    lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);
```

NewsAdapter.java

```
 public class NewsAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
    TextView tvtitle;
    Context context;
    private int color;



    public NewsAdaptor ( Context context, ArrayList <NewsItem> newsList ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.newsList = newsList;
        this.color = Color.RED;
    }

    ArrayList <NewsItem> newsList;


    @Override
    public int getCount () {

        return newsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem ( int position ) {

        return newsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId ( int position ) {
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.newsitemlist_layout, null);

        }
        NewsItem currentNews = newsList.get(position);
        tvtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1id);

        tvtitle.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
        tvtitle.setTextColor(color);
        return convertView;
    }
    public void setTextColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

NewsItem.java

```
public class NewsItem implements Serializable {

String title;

public String getTitle () {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle ( String title ) {
    this.title = title;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}
```

NewsItemlist.layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1id"
        android:layout_width="237dp"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pubDateid"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pubDateid"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="News TITLE"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Adaptor.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference" .

This is because you're never creating the adapter inside your Activity but the you're trying it modify it.

You need to access it via the fragment because the adapter is inside the fragment. So, create a public method in your fragment something like this:

```
public changeAdapterTextColor(int color) {
  if(adaptor == null) {
     Log.e("FRAGMENT", "please initialize the adaptop!");
     return;
  }

  adaptor.setTextColor(color);
  adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

then you can update the adapter by using something like the following inside your Activity:

```
aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         if(isChecked) {
           // Assume the fragment is attached and use mFragment as pointer
           mFragment.changeAdapterTextColor(Color.GREEN);
         } else {
           mFragment.changeAdapterTextColor(Color.RED);
         }
       }
    });
```

Comment: please initialize the adaptor Log Why adapter is not initialized if I place this code directly inside fragment and exquisite with button work fine.

Comment: because you haven't initialize it with something like this: `adaptor = new NewsAdaptor(..)`

Comment: (..) what is that

Comment: I knew adapter is not initialize I mensition this in question. tell me how to initialize